# Вычисление квадратного корня без библиотечных методов

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык

Как можно вычислить квадратный корень без использования `sqrt(n)` и `n^0.5`?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BD.D1.8F

Comment: Если это реальная проблема, объясните, чем стандартный корень не подходит. Если это учебное задание, думайте сами, иначе вы ничему не научитесь. У нас не принято делать задания за студентов.

Comment: кстати, есть ещё [инстрики](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524342). Они как бы не библиотечные функции. Более того, если все правильно сделать, то можно по 4 числа одновременно обрабатывать. Да, современные компиляторы их обычно и используют, когда пишем `sqrt()`.

Comment: из-за таких как VladD портится русскоязычное комьюнити, вопрос непростой, человек может понять пытается, что там за функцией написано, а его сразу называют студентом и пафосно *******тся "У нас не принято делать задания для студентов", уже успел разделить людей на "мы (элита русскоязычного комьюнити, которые всегда назовут студентами и отправят читать документацию)" и студентов, которые ищут халявы на стековерфлоу

Answer (score 13):

Вопрос на самом деле имеет множество решений.

Самый банальный - метод половинного деления.

```
double l = 0;
double r = 1e100; //большое число
double m;
while (r - l > 1e-8){ //точность
    m = l + (r - l)/2;
    if (m*m > n) l = m;
            else r = m; 
}
//ответ в l
```

Есть более оригинальные способы, например симуляция вычисления в столбик (вот [пример](http://hijos.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/root2.jpg), код приводить не буду )

Способ больше для C, но думаю можно использовать и в Java. [Объяснение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );                
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1 итерация
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2 итерация, можно удалить
    return 1/y;
}
```

Можно использовать логарифмы

```
return Math.exp( Math.log(n) / 2);
```

Можно использовать численные методы, например  [метод Ньютона](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/roots_newton)

```
double x = 1;
for (;;) {
   double nx = (x + n / x) / 2;
   if (abs (x - nx) < 1e-10)  break; //точность
   x = nx;
}
```

Существует и много других способов, всё зависит от конкретных требований.

Comment: `for(int i=2; i <= 9;i++) {`
            `if(number%i == 0) {`
                `if(number/i == i) {`
                    `root = true;`
                    `System.out.println("Корень - " + i);`
                `}`
            `}`
        `}`

Я сделал так. подходит?

Comment: @Tsyklop кхм... для точных квадратов в пределах 81 походит.

Answer (score 5):

Напишите свою собственную функцию вычисления квадратного корня, используя [метод Ньютона (касательных)](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/roots_newton) по формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] :

```
public static double sqrt(int number) {
    double t;     
    double squareRoot = number / 2;     
    do {
        t = squareRoot;
        squareRoot = (t + (number / t)) / 2;
    } while ((t - squareRoot) != 0);     
    return squareRoot;
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/BVVtKw)

Comment: А по какому принципу тут всё происходит? Мне вот тупому непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский метод касательных, он же Ньютона. `number / 2` - начальное приближение.

Comment: @pavel я к тому, что пояснение было бы неплохо.....а не `Напишите свою собственную функцию вычисления` ...... как будто он сам изобрел...... шлёпнул код, а дальше как хотите то и делайте

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прогони в дебагере и посмотри. всё понятно станет.Мне вот лично понятно стало. Спасибо автору.

Comment: @Tsyklop зря вы так. Лучше понимать метод, иначе можно попасть на ограничение метода например по точности или по параметрам или ещё как-то. Вот например http://ideone.com/gEyg3D ооочень тонкий код

Comment: @Tsyklop посыл мой был всё же не на то, что я совсем не бум бум, а на то, что автор не удосужился объяснить что это и для чего, чтоб можно было хотя бы остальным, кто решит узнать ответ на сий вопрос - посмотреть и почерпнуть знания, а не просто копи паст.... на что, в прицнипе, сподвигает сий товарищ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский теперь могут черпать знания - поправил, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от контекста задачи. Про различные методы уже рассказали. Есть еще вариант для случая если примерно известен диапазон входных параметров. Можно просто сделать таблицу с уже готовыми ответами.

Когда делали курсовую по микросхемотехнике для 8 битных систем, то самым простым и быстрым решением была ПЗУ на 256 ячеек с уже зашитыми туда ответами. Но преподователь с таким подходом не согласился. Предложил все же "посчитать".